# Text Input with Scrollbar

Tags: html, css

From W3C documents it appears that overflow property can be applied only to block container, So `overflow: scroll` will not work for input element, right?

Is it possible to have scrollbar (specifically horizontal) on a text input directly,  not an adjustment with div or any other element.

Comment: use `textarea` instead

Comment: You should use `textarea` instead of `input`.

Comment: I am not designing anything. I want to specifically about input textfield.